# Windows 10 prevent windows snapping from spawning sub menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, window

When I snap a window to a side of the screen in windows 10, in the portion of the screen that is no occupied by the recently snapped window, a menu of all other windows spawns. From here you can select another window to snap to the unoccupied space.

Is there a way to disable this such that when I snap a window, no menu spawns, and the action is simple done with?

Comment: A screenshot might help explain what you looking to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I gather, I believe you are referring to this interface after snapping:

[image]

**If so,** you can disable this by opening **Settings** in your start menu and selecting the `System` option.

[image]

From there you will select the `Multitasking` tab on the left and disable the setting `When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it`

[image]

Let me know if that helps!